# Python gRPC server in production?

Tags: python-3.x, grpc

Can I just run the [gRPC Python server](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/python.html#starting-the-server) in production or do I need something like [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) in front?

**UPDATE 2020-01-05**: To be more specific to *0script0* follow up I add: ... without making security concessions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, running a gRPC Python server in production is fine.

Answer (score -1):

No. You should have at least nginx (or other) with grpc upstreams.

Comment: Could you support your answer with research?

Comment: Can not understand your question. At least you could set up a number of upstream  servers, authentication,  timeouts and lot more with nginx.also to configure logg9ng and default responses in case upstream is down.

Comment: My question asked if I can run it directly in production without something in front. Your answer states no but does not say why?

Comment: Because it allows you to balance multiple upstreams at least and handle dozens of situations like timeouts, max body size, auth, connections and so on.

Comment: Ok sorry, let me refresh my question "Can it be run in production without making security concessions?"